# Pass data from server to winform app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have an asp.net website and a winform application.
From the winform app (client) user can browse to the website (using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser) and select items. 
After the selection the website (server side) redirect the page with all the items as parameters via query string and on navigating the winform app use that data.

In my opinion this is a bad method for a number of reasons one of them is the query string length limitation (2083 characters in IE).

What other methods are recommended in this case?

Thank you

Comment: Use POST verb instead of GET. There is no limit.

Comment: may I also advise you to use [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @vasily.sib The user is using the displayed web page. HttpClient does not solve any problem here.

Comment: you are right, that's way I only _advise_ him to redesign his app. I mean, if your application is just a `WebBrowser` - then just use a normal web browser, like chrome or any other

Comment: @vasily.sib How do you recommend on using chrome web browser via winform?

Comment: I recommend to not use winform

Comment: I am afraid this is not an option for me... This application is based on winform and  this is necessary to be able to open webpage and select the items from the asp.net app. I am looking for a better option to transfer the data instead of querystring.

Comment: ok, then can you pleas clarify. You said that it is _"the website (server side) redirect the page with all the items as parameters via query string"_. Are you sure? What you are talking about is **very** uncommon behavior.

Comment: @vasily.sib Yes, unfortunately I am sure.... Another team worked on the projects and now I want to make it right.  Example how it looks now on server side: window.location=www.google.com?item=12234&number=5678 etc.

Comment: Can't you just post the data/selections the user makes on the website to the server.  Then have the winform app simply retrieve those selections.  Costs you an extra trip to the server but that seems like that would be easiest.

Comment: @jaredbaszler Can you elaborate on how to retrieve the selections? What to use to achieve that?

Comment: @Guid2015 - whatever information your wanting to send back with in your query string, you need to store that information to the database instead.  Make a new table, columns, etc. Then once it is saved, your WinForms app can retrieve it.  This removes the hassle of trying to get a WinForms app and MVC app to communicate.